# Axios customizable base URL

Tags: axios

Is there any way to make a customizable URL with axios? For example, I've created an axios instance:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'localhost:8001/**test**/service/**test**/method' ,    
  });

export default instance;
```

Now I want to use this instance in many places in my project, but when I call this instance I'd like to change both `**test**` with params I pass to it.

Is that possible?

Comment: Typically you'd just set `"localhost:8001"` as the `baseURL`, then in the method where you use that instance supply the specific path with any parameters baked in: `inst.get(\`/${first}/service/${second}/method\`)`.

Answer (score -1):

Make a function

```js
function createAxios(string) {
    return axios.create({baseUrl: `localhost:8001/${string}/service/**test**/method`})
}
```

So when you want it another place, just write

```
const instance = createAxios("test")
```

Comment: that url is not baseUrl in the first place and this answer becomes misleading because of that.